# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'demofile.txt'

Tags: python

can someone tell me why when I want to open a text file with python
my output is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'demofile.txt'
even though the file is already in the same folder and the writing is correct.[image: Here's the file and folder]

and this is my code
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
print(f.read())

thank you before

Comment: Better use an absolute path to the file.

Comment: please insert full path of the demofile.text. EX-c/admin/.../demofile.text

Comment: thank you very much, it's finished,must give the full folder name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of the Python file and the current working directory can differ. `open` uses the current working directory if you use a relative path. The obvious fix is to use an absolute path. But then you will have to edit the code each time you copy the script to a different folder.

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to create an absolute path based on the current running scripts location. Put this in a Python script, run it and look at the result.

```
import pathlib

print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent)
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'demofile.txt')
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'data' / 'demofile.txt')
```

So your code can be changed to

```
filepath = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'demofile.txt'
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `with`

```
with open("demofile.txt","r") as f:
    f.read()
```

Maybe, You are executing python file with absolute path that's why FileNotFound.
Try with absolute path. Like, `c:\files\demofile.txt`

Comment: thank you very much, it's finished,must give the full folder name

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the answer of Mathias, I had the same problem but with an image, then you need to write

`import pathlib`

`print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent)`
`print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'name_of_your_file.extension')`
`print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'data' / 'name_of_your_file.extension')`

Answer (score 0):

already done the correct answer is to use the name of the specific folder where the text files are located
thank you very much, everyone